# Flutter: increase the size of the SwitchListTile icon

Tags: flutter

I am using SwitchListTile in my app and it works good. However, I need to style it.. I would like to make the switch icon bigger..

How do this?

[image]

```
SwitchListTile(
  dense: true,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
       agreeSmsAlerts = value;
    });
 },
 value: agreeSmsAlerts,
 title: Text(
   "sign up for job alerts",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
 ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to increase the size of the switch icon, you can wrap `SwitchListTile` with `Transform.scale`, but the scale would be applied to entire widget, ie, to the text as well, that messes up the size of entire `SwitchListTile` widget, as shown below:

[image]

To avoid this, you can use `Switch` widget instead of `SwitchListTile` and wrap it in `Row` widget and provide `mainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` to properly align the text and increased icon size. Here's how:

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children:
                <Widget>[
                  Text('Sign up for job alerts'),
                  Transform.scale(
                    scale: 1.8,
                    child: Switch(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          agreeSmsAlerts = value;
                        });
                      },
                      value: agreeSmsAlerts,
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
```

And the output is:

[image]

You can provide the `scale` value per your requirement, depending on how big you want it.
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: How to increase just the width?

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but just adding to @Darshan 's solution above (which works but would result in the user not being able to click on the text in order to change the switch), you can just wrap the text portion of the switch widget in a Transform widget:

```
SwitchListTile(
  dense: true,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
       agreeSmsAlerts = value;
    });
 },
 value: agreeSmsAlerts,
 title: Transform.scale(
           scale: 1.8,
           child: Text(
             "sign up for job alerts",
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
           ),
        ),
 ),
```

),